# Python HTTPServer: Reponse not getting sent (Looking to return JSON)

Tags: python, json

Hey there I am working on a Basic server with Python now I am testing out how I can return JSON data, but then now I am failing to return  that JSON data.

**This is how I am trying to send back JSON to client:**

```
response= {
   "name":'junior',
   "name":'junior'
}
self.send_response(200)
self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False), 'utf-8'))
self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
self.end_headers()
```

**Below is the entire source code:**

```
import ast
import json
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http import HTTPStatus

class ServiceHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    
  def do_GET(self):
    print(self.path)


  def do_POST(self):
    content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
    post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)  
    body = ast.literal_eval(post_body.decode("utf-8"))
    response= {
       "name":'junior',
       "name":'junior'
    }
    self.send_response(200)
    self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False), 'utf-8'))
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()
        
   
#Server Initialization
server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1',8080), ServiceHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Can I please get some help on how I can return back JSON data

Comment: What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: **Current behavior** is not response message is getting sent back to the client and **Expected behavior** is me sending back json  object back to client

Comment: Ok, so I'm not too sure how the stdlib http server works, but I'm pretty sure that the body should be sent after the headers have been sent

Comment: Oh yea my bad the, did not spot that however problem still stands not json is getting returned

Comment: Make a [mcve]..

Comment: @MarkTolonen Just gave entire source code that should reproduce problem faced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send headers before the body like this:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False), 'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The headers have to be sent before the data, but also how are you asking for the POST request?  Here's an example that just uses a GET:

```py
import json
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class ServiceHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        response= {
           "name":'junior',
           "name2":'junior'
        }
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        data = json.dumps(response).encode()
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response).encode())

server = HTTPServer(('',8080), ServiceHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

```
>>> print(requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080').json())
{'name': 'junior', 'name2': 'junior'}
```